# SQLAlchemy - Changing column values on update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I update column value by 1 in the table when one of the rows is updated? For e.g. Suppose I have a bunch of rows with value as --

```
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3
D - 4
E - 5
```

and now if I update the value of D to 2, table rest of values should increment by 1 as --

```
A - 1
D - 2
B - 3
C - 4
E - 5
```

This is like a sorting order change done through UI.

Comment: I think sqlalchemy or database backend doesn't support this operation, you must sort it in your code then write it back. Remember lock the whole table.

Comment: @YangHG Was hoping for something along the lines of trigger (mapper -> after_update)